# how to substring text in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am using VBScript

I have got below text

```
str = "tcm:1-245-9"
```

Now I want to substring above string in such a way, so that I get the output as below

`pstr = "245"` from the above string,

Please let me know suggestions in VBScript only.

Thanks.

Comment: Will the format always be the same. Why not use split?

Comment: yes the format will always be same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the string format will always be like that:

```
segments = Split(str,"-")
pstr = segments(1)
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use

```
Mid(string,start[,length]) 

string - Required. The string expression from which characters are returned

start  - Required. Specifies the starting position. If set to greater than the number of characters in string, it returns an empty string ("")

length  - Optional. The number of characters to return
```

or use

```
Split(expression[,delimiter[,count[,compare]]]) 

expression - Required. A string expression that contains substrings and delimiters

delimiter  - Optional. A string character used to identify substring limits. Default is the space character

count      - Optional. The number of substrings to be returned. -1 indicates that all substrings are returned

compare    - Optional. Specifies the string comparison to use.

            Can have one of the following values:
              * 0 = vbBinaryCompare - Perform a binary comparison
              * 1 = vbTextCompare - Perform a textual comparison
```

Comment: index range for start?